# how to append to a c# list from form controls

Tags: c#, wpf, list

I have a form with several text boxes. I want to use the input in the text boxes to append to a list in c# which I then want to show in a datagrid as the enteries are entered. But I have an issue. I add the data to the textboxes hit the display to datagrid button I have created and it seems ever time instead of appending items to the list the list is recreated. What am I doing wrong?

'''

```
{
    public LotScan()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    public class LotData
    {
        public string Lot;
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int PO { get; set; }
        public string MfgPart { get; set; }
    }

    // code to add from control data to list
    private List<LotData> LoadCollectionData()
    {
        List<LotData> lot = new List<LotData>();
        lot.Add(new LotData()
        {
            Lot = LotNo.Text,
            Description = frmDescription.Text,
            PO = int.Parse(frmPO.Text),
            MfgPart = frmMfgPart.Text,
        });
        return lot;

    }

    //button to add list data to datagrid on form
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {          
        gridLotData.ItemsSource = LoadCollectionData();

        LotNo.Text = String.Empty;
        frmMfgPart.Text = string.Empty;
        frmDescription.Text = String.Empty;
        frmMfgPart.Text = string.Empty;
        frmPO.Text = string.Empty;
    }
```

'''

Comment: The first line of `LoadCollectionData` initializes a new list. So every time you call this a new List with one entry is being created and returned. You need to make the `List<LogData> lot` a class variable, not a local one inside the method. Then in the method you just call `lot.Add(...` with your data. The fact that you're using `new` when updating the list should give you the hint you need, because you dont want a new list, you just want to add to your existing list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public LotScan()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        gridLotData.ItemsSource = LotDataList;
    }

    private LotData LoadCollectionData()
    {
        return new LotData()
        {
            Lot = LotNo.Text,
            Description = frmDescription.Text,
            PO = int.Parse(frmPO.Text),
            MfgPart = frmMfgPart.Text,
        };

    }

    public class LotData
    {
        public string Lot;
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int PO { get; set; }
        public string MfgPart { get; set; }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<LotData> LotDataList = new ObservableCollection<LotData>();

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LotDataList.Add(LoadCollectionData());
        LotNo.Text = String.Empty;
        frmMfgPart.Text = string.Empty;
        frmDescription.Text = String.Empty;
        frmMfgPart.Text = string.Empty;
        frmPO.Text = string.Empty;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Move this variable to be a private Member variable (just put it a line above the classes constructor method):

```
List<LotData> lot = new List<LotData>();
```